# Hover tooltip by group in ggvis

Tags: r, hover, tooltip, ggvis

I want to be able to hover over a given point and be able to see information about that specific point and have it pop up larger than the others.  That's done in the code below.

```
all_values <- function(x) {
  if(is.null(x)) return(NULL)
  paste0(names(x), ": ", format(x), collapse = "<br />")
}

iris %>% 
  ggvis(~Sepal.Length,~Petal.Length) %>%
    layer_points(size := 50, fill.hover := "yellow", size.hover := 200) %>% 
    add_tooltip(all_values, "hover")
```

Is there a way for all the points sharing the same `Species` variable as the selected point to have this highlighting applied to them as well?  In my real data, the fill and shape variables are being used to convey other information, so I need a way to quickly highlight an entire group.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really answering your question spot on, but have you considered using the fill property to group your data visually?

```
layer_points(size := 50, fill = ~Species)
```

Comment: As I said, this doesn't work due to the fill being used with another variable.  However, I did find the functionality I was looking for by switching from `ggvis` to `ScatterD3`, which reduces the opacity of all points that are not in the same defined group as the selected point.

Comment: Nice to hear that you found a working solution! I will check out ScatterD3 myself.